# How do I color-fill in a specific Excel cell using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, package, openpyxl

I'm currently using `openpyxl` to modify specific excel cells. I am able to modify font styles very easily, simply just:

```
ws['A1'].font = Font(color=colors.White)
```

But I am unable to change the fill of the specific cell. Anyone know any documentation about how to do this? I want to just change the color of one cell, so what other packages are required?

I tried exploring some other things like `PatternFill`, but I haven't been able to accurately get what I'm looking for. All I need is to change the fill color of a single cell.

Answer (score 1):

What was the [PatternFill](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.styles.fills.html?highlight=patternfill#openpyxl.styles.fills.PatternFill) code that you tried using? Is it something similar to this?

```
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

redFill = PatternFill(start_color='FFEE1111', end_color='FFEE1111', fill_type='solid')
```

Then to apply to a specific cell use:

```
ws['A1'].fill = redFill
```

Or for grading:

```
fill = PatternFill(fill_type=None, start_color='FFFFFFFF', end_color='FF000000')
```

Comment: Hey, 

I tried using the first one, however I do not notice any visual changes to the excel file I have open. Furthermore, I want to be able to only change the color of a single cell, and I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that. What I'm trying to do is if a cell has a certain criteria met, fill in the cell with a different color

Comment: when is `redFill` defined? don't you mean just the recently defined `fill`?