# OpenPyXL: AttributeError when trying to set fill

Tags: python, excel, windows, openpyxl

```
    ws.cell(row=greenBegin+1, column=3).style.fill.fill_type = 'solid'

    ws.cell(row=greenBegin+1, column=3).style.fill.start_color.index = '0000FF'

    ws.cell(row=greenBegin+1, column=3).style.fill.end_color.index = '0000FF'
```

I'm attempting to set the fill of a cell to solid green using this code, but I always get "AttributeError: can't set attribute" when I run the code. I've tried different styling methods, but there isn't a whole lot of information on this library AFAIK which is bothersome to say the least as I'm using it for a work project.

Comment: I don't use python but a quick search yielded [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484220/python-fill-cells-with-colors-using-openpyxl) Hope this helps?

Comment: Another [ONE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904765/how-do-i-color-fill-in-a-specific-excel-cell-using-openpyxl)

Comment: Or [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440284/setting-styles-in-openpyxl)

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot to actually reply, but yes, the first link you sent worked.

Comment: `Thank you so much! I forgot to actually reply, but yes, the first link you sent worked. –  Luke Faez 4 hours ago` Thanks for reverting :)

Answer (score -1):

This is covered in the documentation. Styles are immutable and therefore cannot be edited in place. They must be reassigned.

http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.0-b1/styles.html

`ws.cell(…).fill = Fill(…)`

Comment: I already linked your answer in my first comment. Reposting the same answer with a slight variation doesn't make sense.